# C# XML ToList inside ToList

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following C# code and I have no idea why it's not working (I'm getting a NullReferenceException error). If I define Recipe as new List() everything starts working OK.

```
foreach (XElement element in document.Descendants("vegetables"))
        {
            VegetablesList = (
                from vegetables in element.Elements()
                select new FoodItem()
                {
                    Name = (vegetables.Element("name") == null) ? null : vegetables.Element("name").Value.ToString(),
                    Bcg = (vegetables.Element("bcg") == null) ? null : vegetables.Element("bcg").Value.ToString(),
                    Info = (vegetables.Element("info") == null) ? null : vegetables.Element("info").Value.ToString(),
                    Recipes = (
                        from recipes in element.Element("recipes").Elements()
                        select new Recipe()
                        {
                            Name = (recipes.Element("name") == null) ? null : recipes.Element("name").Value.ToString(),
                            Text = (recipes.Element("text") == null) ? null : recipes.Element("text").Value.ToString()
                        }
                    ).ToList()
                }
            ).ToList();
            VegetablesListBox.ItemsSource = VegetablesList;
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What line of code is giving you the null reference exception?

Comment: Why do you repeatedly assign `VegetablesList` to `ItemsSource` ?

Comment: BTW use `Name = (string)recipes.Element("name")`  it would make you code a whole lot easier to read.

Comment: I'm getting the error on new FoodItem() { ... }

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I only assign VegetablesListBox.ItemsSource = VegetablesList; - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Fixed! By changing <code>from recipes in element.Element("recipes").Elements()</code> to <code>from recipes in vegetables.Element("recipes").Elements()</code>

Comment: @Philip: your assignment is inside a foreach so unless you only expect to the foreach to iterate once you will assign to `ItemsSource` multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `element.Element("recipes")` returns `null`, which means that the `recipes` element does not exist for that iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed by changing element.Element("recipes").Elements() to vegetables.Element("recipes").Elements()

Comment: Null is a pain in the ass in Linq to XML.  I'm constantly fighting that.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Isn't it great that Linq actually tells you very clearly that you're having a problem with your code though? Instead of just silently returning empty collections making your problems very very hard to debug?!?

Comment: Well, I wound up writing some extension methods to short-circuit all of the nulls and return empty collections. It was just getting way too difficult to check every returned object for null before calling methods on it. Unless live objects are *always* returned, it's pretty much impossible to chain the `Elements()` and `Descendants()` methods, which is what I wanted to do.